# (Av Harachaman,) sh'ma kolenu

Tags: tefilla, minhag, prayer-book

Is there a *[nusach hat'fila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach)* in which the 16th *b'racha* of the *[amida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah)* begins with "אב הרחמן" at *[shacharis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shacharit)* only and skips those words at other *t'filos*?

I heard recently that this is in fact printed in some version of the [Artscroll Siddur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArtScroll#Primary_publications) but I have not seen it inside.

Why would this be so? Isn't one consistent with *[nusach S'farad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard)* and the other with *[nusach Ashkenaz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Ashkenaz)*?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds at first glance as if someone is confused and mixed up Av Harahaman of Shema Koleinu with Ahavah Rabbah of Ahavas Olam in which indeed we find some Hasidim switching to Ahavah Rabbah for Shabbos Shaharis.

Comment: @Yahu I wouldn't rule out confusion. Is it fair to assume that the presence or absence of "שמע קולנו" correlates 100% with נוסח?

Comment: My understanding was that "Av Harahaman, Shemah Kolainu" is what is said, and not skipping "Shemah Kolainu".